# IE throws an exception on "self = this" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, this

I have some objected oriented JS that works fine in firefox but not in IE 8 (though it will be IE 9 that we will need to support).

When I do: 
 "self = this;"
  IE flags that as an error. 
  I am trying to set this to self to then use it in a jquery callback to call some other
 method in my JS object.

```
this.upd_params = function () {
   $("#add-parameter-modal").modal('hide');

   var param_form = $('#add_param_form');
   self = this;
   this.added_params = [];
   this.removed_params = [];

   $('.unused_parameter').each(function (index, obj) {
     if (obj.checked) {
       id = self.get_idnum(obj.id);
       self.add_param2list(id);
     }
   });


   $('.used_parameter').each(function (index, obj) {
     if (!obj.checked) {
       id = self.get_idnum(obj.id);
       self.remove_param(id);
     }
   });

   this.upd_html();

   cfg_form_changed = true;

};
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish Oh, missed that entirely :)

Answer (score 19):

Make sure `self` is a locally-scoped (not global) variable.

```
var self = this;
```

Otherwise, `self` refers to [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self) and assigning to it is not allowed.

Comment: FF will just ignore the assignment. IE will throw an exception on the assignment.

Comment: @pst Thanks for being more specific.  Either way, though, it's not the desired behavior.

Comment: Was about a minute away from clawing one of my eyes out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i'm posting this because i believe its related and can be useful to others, 
if you do inline variable assigning, as the code below:

```
var var1 = value1,
    var2 = value2,
    self= this;
```

it will throw an Exception on IE saying Not Implemented.

You can fix it by changing to something like this:

```
var var1 = value1,
    var2 = value2;

var self= this;
```